# PreviousSibling doesn't return value using querySelector

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to extract two parts from Local html file located in C:\Sample.html
And I used @QHarr code from another thread like that

```
Sub Test()
Dim html As HTMLDocument, post As Object, i As Long

Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Sample.html")
Set post = html.querySelectorAll("span.course-player__chapter-item__completion")

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Trim(post.item(i).innerText)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = post.item(i).PreviousSibling.innerText
Next i
End Sub

Function GetHTMLFileContent(ByVal filePath As String) As HTMLDocument
Dim fso As Object, hFile As Object, hString As String, html As HTMLDocument

Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set hFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)

Do Until hFile.AtEndOfStream
    hString = hFile.ReadAll()
Loop

html.body.innerHTML = hString
Set GetHTMLFileContent = html
End Function
```

The code works fine and grabs the innertext of the element in that part `post.item(i).innerText`.
But when trying to get the innertext of the Previous Sibling it doesn't return anything

Here's snapshot of the html

[image]

```html
<div class="course-player__chapter-item__header _chapter-item__header_d57kmg ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
  <h2 tabindex="-1" class="course-player__chapter-item__title _chapter-item__title_d57kmg">
    <span class="course-player__progress _chapter-item__progress_d57kmg">
      <span data-percentage-completion="100" class="_chapter-item__progress-ring_d57kmg">
        <span class="progress-ring__ring _progress-ring__ring_jgsecr">
 <span class="progress-ring__mask progress-ring--full _progress-ring__mask_jgsecr _progress-ring--full_jgsecr">
  <span class="progress-ring--fill brand-color__background _progress-ring--fill_jgsecr"></span>
 </span>
 <span class="progress-ring__mask progress-ring--half _progress-ring__mask_jgsecr ">
  <span class="progress-ring--fill brand-color__background _progress-ring--fill_jgsecr"></span>
  <span class="progress-ring--fill progress-ring--fix _progress-ring--fill_jgsecr _progress-ring--fix_jgsecr"></span>
 </span>
</span>
<span class="progress-ring__ring-inset _progress-ring__ring-inset_jgsecr"></span>
<span class="progress-ring__checkmark brand-color__text _progress-ring__checkmark_jgsecr"><i aria-label="Completed" class="toga-icon toga-icon-checkmark"></i></span>

      </span>
    </span>

    INTRO TO VBA - Overview

<!---->
    <span class="course-player__chapter-item__completion _chapter-item__completion_d57kmg">
      10 / 10
    </span>

    <span class="course-player__chapter-item__toggle _chapter-item__toggle_d57kmg">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="chapter-item__toggle-icon toga-icon toga-icon-caret-stroke-down _chapter-item__toggle-icon_d57kmg"></i>
    </span>

  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't any content in the previous sibling - The INTRO TO VBA isn't in a <span>

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what is the best way to get the text `INTRO TO VBA - Overview`?

Comment: Just make it <span>INTRO TO VBA - Overview</span> and then it will be the previous sibling

Comment: You mean to change the html!! Or I misunderstand you?!

Comment: Yes, and you're missing a closing </span>

Comment: The html is exactly as in the website ..I am sure of that. I can get both in one column using `h2[class='course-player__chapter-item__title _chapter-item__title_d57kmg']` but I need to separate each in two columns

Comment: Without changing the html, the 'INTRO TO VBA - Overview' is in the parent element, along with the '10/10' span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the CSS Selector that returns all the value using `h2[class='course-player__chapter-item__title _chapter-item__title_d57kmg']` then split the output into two columns

```
Sub Test()
Dim x, html As HTMLDocument, post As Object, s As String, i As Long

Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Sample.html")
Set post = html.querySelectorAll("h2[class='course-player__chapter-item__title _chapter-item__title_d57kmg']")

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
    x = Split(Trim(post.item(i).innerText), " ")
    s = Join(Array(x(UBound(x)), x(UBound(x) - 1), x(UBound(x) - 2)), " ")
    ReDim Preserve x(0 To UBound(x) - 3)

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Trim(Join(x, " "))
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = Trim(s)
Next i
End Sub
```